# Short post with hashtag

Tags: wordpress, post, tags, short

I'm looking for a feature on WordPress website. 
I want to have a block with single or double line news which will be related to each other with hashtags.

Example:

Kotaku is reporting that 2020's Call of Duty is now a Treyarch-led Call of Duty: Black Ops 5 as opposed to a new game by Raven Software and Sledgehammer Games. #callofduty #blackops #COD

---

Watch Dogs Legion is Officially Confirmed by Ubisoft; More Info Coming at E3 #watchdogs #E3 #ubisoft

---

When the user clicks on tags will have access to news like the above examples with the same tag.

Is there any plugin or code for it?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have you tried custom taxonomies? 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy

Comment: You can just add a _#_ in front of building tags in WP.